# TensorFlow error when save/restore dynamic_RNN model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I can save and restore model if the model is CNN, but I can't restore RNN.

I made RNN network like this.
I wanna save trained weigh and bias or model. And I want to predict without training. following is main.py

```
#main.py
tf_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, seq_length, data_dim], name='tf_x')
tf_y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, output_dim], name='tf_y')

rnn_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=hidden_dim)
outputs, (h_c, h_n) = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn( rnn_cell,
                                         tf_x,
                                         initial_state=None,
                                         dtype=tf.float32,
                                         time_major=False )

output = tf.layers.dense(outputs[:, -1, :], output_dim, name='dense_output')
loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=tf_y, logits=output)
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(LR).minimize(loss)
accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy( labels=tf.argmax(tf_y, axis=1), predictions=tf.argmax(output, axis=1),)[1]

with tf.Session as sess:
    init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer()) # the local var is for accuracy_op
    sess.run(init_op)     # initialize var in graph

    ...(training)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    save_path = saver.save(sess, "Save data/RNN-model")
    saver.export_meta_graph(filename="Save Data/RNN-model.meta", as_text=True)
```

and in "run.py" I tried to load that data.

```
#run.py 
...(same as main.py)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state('Save data/')
    saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("Save data/RNN-model.meta")
    ... (prediction)
```

result is..

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Key dense/bias not found in checkpoint
```

What do you think is the problem?

Comment: (1) in run.py put `saver` inside `with` block (2) double check that your model constructed with python code "...(same as main.py)" is actually the same (refactor the common code into a separate file to avoid copy-paste errors) (3) if you construct model with the code and then restore the weights you don't have to import metagraph (do either one or another)

Comment: It might help you: https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/issues/527

Comment: @Drop Thanks. I put saver inside with, delete code concerning metagraph and check code. But now `Attempting to use uninitialized value accuracy/total` FailedPreconditionError raised.